# How do I make grails' get to throw exception on record not found?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want get method to throw an exception when record is not found. I don't want to test whether result is null or not.

Comment: You will probably need some meta programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exceptions are expensive, and even more so in Groovy because of all the extra stack frames. When you trigger or throw an expected exception you're incurring the cost of filling in the stack frames, and although this isn't very costly for one instance, it will add up in production. Check out this writeup, but realize that the performance would be much worse if there were an additional run with Groovy: http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/

Having said that, one quick way I can think of to trigger exceptions for missing rows is to use the `load` method instead of `get`. `load` never returns null, it always returns a proxy with the id stored inside. As soon as you reference any properties other than the id, Hibernate goes to the database and throws an exception if there's no row for that id.

A more straightforward option would be to add a static method to your domain class that uses `get` but does the null check for you, e.g.

```
class MyDomainClass {

   ...

   static MyDomainClass retrieve(id) {
      MyDomainClass instance = MyDomainClass.get(id)
      if (instance == null) {
         throw new NotGotException(id)
      }
      instance
   }

   static class NotGotException extends RuntimeException {
      NotGotException(id) {
         super("No MyDomainClass found for id $id")
      }

      Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
         return this
      }
   }
}
```

Here I override `fillInStackTrace` to do nothing to avoid the cost of unnecessarily gathering unneeded and expensive information.